# Testing equality of variances without the data, just from the variances and the mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, binomial-distribution, levenes-test

Assume I have a physical system in which I am sampling data from either a binomial distribution with a $p$ of 0.5, or from an alternation between a $p$ of 0.25 and 0.75. But the result is such that in this case it appears $p = 0.5$ as well.

So lets say for example I do a 1000 coinflips and get 500 heads. So the $\hat{p}=0.5$. Now I want to determine the probability I am sampling from the static case rather than the alternating case by looking at the variance within the data. Because if in the first half of the coinflip series I had noticeably more heads than expected from $p=0.5$ and in the last part less, I want to be able to see that.

I have [a paper where they propose doing the following](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3059737/pdf/main.pdf):

- cut the dataset into $M$ windows of $n=5$ coinflips.
- for each of these windows, determine the number of heads.
- calculate the variance between these datasets.

Or formally: $Var[\hat{h}] = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{M} (h_i - \mu_i)^2}{M}$, where $h_i$ is the number of heads within a window of size $n=5$ and $\mu_i$ is the mean of the number of heads in such windows.

They then do monte-carlo simulations to calculate a 99.9% confidence interval for the static case in order to be able to say if the deviation is significant. But this is the part I don't like because the data is distributed binomially and Monte-Carlo is computationally expensive.

I was wondering if we could use our knowledge that under the null-hypothesis we are looking at a binomial static system instead, as such:

- calculate the number of windows, e.g. $M=1000/5$.
- calculate the theoretical variance for each window -> $np(1-p)$ with $n=5$ and $p=0.5$. So this results in a constant of $\frac{5}{4}$ for each window.
- The variance for the entire dataset should therefore be $Mnp(1-p)$ since variances are additive. Therefore $Var[h]_{(theory)} = \frac{5M}{4}$ from theory.

I then have the theoretical variance $Var[h]_{(theory)}$ for the dataset assuming the data draws from a single binomial, and the 'measured' variance $Var[\hat{h}]$ from the actual data itself.

How do I now best test if these variances are significantly different? We already know that the means are identical, if this might help. And what's very important to me is that all I am presented with in the end are these two variances, $M$ and the observed $\hat{p}$. I do not want to have to access the actual raw data anymore because the calculations are expensive.

Is there a test that will help me draw the conclusion from this information? Things I found where F-test, Levene's test, Bertlett etc., but for the last two I get the impression we need to use the actual data again and the first is said to be valid only for normally distributed data.

Comment: I think I follow you, despite some confusing and ambiguous statements in the question. Perhaps the most important thing to clear up is the second bullet in the second set: $np(1-p)$ is constant (equal to $5/4$) as you have defined it and therefore the variance of these $M$ values will always be $0$. I suspect you intended to mean $n\hat{p_i}(1-\hat{p_i})$ where $\hat{p_i}$ is the estimated proportion *within window* $i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,M.$ Is this the case? Also, in the end which *two* variances will you have, given you have described only one?

Comment: @whuber I'm sorry for any confusion, I'm not familiar with the notation in this field. Yes, you understand me correctly. I do mean $p_i$ as you described it and will change it in the question. However, are you sure that the constant variance per window of $\frac{5}{4}$ will lead to a total variance of 0? Because the way I see it, it's like drawing $M$ a sample of size $n$ from a bowl, therefore the variances add right? And the two variances I am talking about are the one calculated from the actual sample using the published algorithm, and the theoretical value described above. Hope this helps?

Comment: @whuber I cant change my original comment anymore :S. After rereading your comment, what you say about $n\hat{p_i}(1-\hat{p_i})$ closely resembles the original paper, although they calculate it in a different but equivalent way. (See updated question). What I want to calculate is both that variance as well as the one expected purely from theory for such a system, assuming it is static with $p=0.5$.

Comment: If you could provide a link or reference to the paper, that might help clear things up.

Comment: [link](http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/articlerender.fcgi?artid=3059737&tool=pmcentrez&rendertype=abstract). I hope you can read it.